# On click dialog box

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to have an on click dialog box for each of my tickboxes. each one will have their their messages. I am trying to create one for now and the one i am trying it to is `Blue`

```
   <fieldset class="boxoflist">
    <legend>list</legend>
    <li class="field">
        <label class="help">Please select the ones that apply to you</label>
                <label class="listbox " for="check5">
                <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="5">

            <span></span>
            Blue
            </label>

                <label class="listbox " for="check1">
                <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="1">

            <span></span>

            red
            </label>

                <label class="listbox " for="check6">
                <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="6">

            <span></span>

            pink
            </label>

                <label class="listbox " for="check3">
                <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="3">

            <span></span>
            Any
            </label>   
    </li>
 </fieldset>



 <div id="Any-helper">
    <p>S'il vous plaît expliquez ci-dessous ce que vous avez idée de couleur dans le mélange, avec une d   escription claire </p>
    </div>
```

I have tried

```
   $(function() {
    $(".listbox").click(function(){
        $('#Any-helper').dialog ({
        height: 140,
        modal: true
         });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:[**Working Demo of your question**](http://jsfiddle.net/4uwn8/3/).

Import the following scripts in your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

CHECK:

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="checkbox">
    <legend>list</legend>
    <li class="field">
        <label class="help">Please select the ones that apply to you</label>
                <label class="listbox " for="check5">


            <span></span>
            Blue
            </label>

                <label class="listbox " for="check1">
                <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="1" id="blue">

            <span></span>

            red
            </label>

                <label class="listbox " for="check6">
                <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="6" id="red">

            <span></span>

            pink
            </label>

                <label class="listbox " for="check3">
                <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="3" id="pink">

            <span></span>
            Any
            </label>   
    </li>
</fieldset>




<div id="Any-helper">
<p>S'il vous plaît expliquez ci-dessous ce que vous avez idée de couleur dans le mélange, avec une d   escription claire </p>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {

$( "#Any-helper" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 300,
  width: 350,
  modal: true
});
$( "#blue" ).click(function() 
  {
    $( "#Any-helper" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
});
```

Comment: `#blue`? why? blue is not an id

Comment: check the link (http://jsfiddle.net/4uwn8/).... I have modified bit of your HTML code also.

Comment: where did you get `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">` from?

Comment: U can remove that link if u want.

Comment: what exactly you are facing problem, when u run my code??

Comment: i click for`Blue` tickbox and the dialog doesn't pop up. Thats why I am say `#blue` is for an id and i havent assign any id to any of my tickbox options

Comment: On your demo its shows as an input field inside of tickboxes. On the framework am using its shows as a list and when you click on any of the colours its ticks everything and then its shows the dialog box when you click on something else

Comment: see the UPDATE fiddle above.

Comment: damn its not working for me maybe because i have other their called `blue` that is somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
Place the red, blue etc... messages in a span with class "messages" and update message in each click. ("#message_container" is the id of message container in the dialog.)

```
$(function() {
    $(".listbox").click(function(){
    var message = $(this).children('span.messages').html();
    $('#Any-helper #message_container').html(message);
            $('#Any-helper').dialog ({
            height: 140,
            modal: true
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am getting `TypeError: $(...).chiledren is not a function`

Comment: I am very sorry.
Please check the spelling.
Correct chiledren to children. I have corrected it in the answer.

Thanks.